# Laravel 5.1: PDOException: has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, testing, laravel-5.1

I am running functional tests in Laravel 5.1 against a MySQL database on a staging server and get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'username' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20)

The TestCase class looks like:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{

    /**
     * Rollback and execute migrations for each test.
     */
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

    /**
     * Is this the first test.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $isInitialTest = true;

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }

    /**
     * If this is the first test of the actual test suite:
     * Delete all test table records and run migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        if(self::$isInitialTest){

            self::$isInitialTest = false;

            Artisan::call('migrate');
        }
    }

}
```

And a failing test (after a lot of other tests ran successfully) looks like

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class AreasTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Add a new area to a tenant.
     */
    public function testAddArea()
    {
        $tenant = factory('XXX\Tenant', 'xxx')->create();

        $this->visit("admin/tenants/{$tenant->id}")
            ->click('…')
            ->click('N…')
            ->type('…', 'name')
            ->press('…')
            ->see('…');
    }
…
}
```

I am running the tests like this 
`vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap ./bootstrap/autoload.php ./tests/`

Is there anything beside raising `max_user_connections` I can do to control how much parallel db connections are open? If possible I do not want to slow down the tests :)

On my local dev machine `max_user_connections` is set to `0` so there is no limitation and no error.

Comment: How are you opening all the user connections? Can you show us a test and perhaps how you're running it?

Comment: I am not sure how I open all the user connections, my guess is that the Laravel framework opens one connection for each test (there are 45 tests at the moment) and does not reuse the available connection/s. Does that makes sense?
I added an example test and the command I use to run the tests.